# Sympy: print a symbol instead of its corresponding name

Tags: python, sympy

For esthetic reasons, I sometimes define my symbols, for instance, as `Xeexx = symbols('chi__xx_ee')` so that they end up being nicely displayed with Latex. However, I also sometimes need to manually edit the result from equations containing many of such symbols so that I can then further process them. Is there thus a way of printing a symbol instead of its corresponding name ?

Consider this example:

```
from sympy import symbols, expand

Xeexx = symbols('chi__xx_ee')

pol = expand( (Xeexx + 2) ** 2 )
print(pol)
```

which outputs:

```
chi__xx_ee**2 + 4*chi__xx_ee + 4
```

Instead of this output, I wish to obtain

```
Xeexx**2 + 4*Xeexx + 4
```

Comment: `Xeexx` isn't the symbol. That's the name of a variable you used to hold a reference to the symbol. The symbol itself holds no information about the `Xeexx` name.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment:

```
Xeexx = symbols('chi__xx_ee')
```

Creates a `sympy` object (***chi*** with superscript **xx** and subscript **ee**, if I understood correctly). The fact that this object is pointed to by a Python variable named `Xeexx` is not part of the data maintained by that object (or by any `sympy` object, for that matter). It is therefore not practical to assume you can get the result you want without registering, in any way, the name of the variable.

So, why not just do:

```
from sympy import symbols, expand

Xeexx = symbols('Xeexx')
pol = expand( (Xeexx + 2) ** 2 )
print(pol)
```

The output you would get is going to be:

```
Xeexx**2 + 4*Xeexx + 4
```

Of course, you lose the super/subscript info from the original symbol name, but you get your desired output.

Comment: That is indeed what I am currently doing but it does not really solve the original issue.

Comment: @Andro - what is the original issue? Why can't you either use the simplified name (the one the is currently the variable name) as the symbol name, or the one you are currently using (with the super and subscript)?